# How to periodically reload jQGrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, reload

I am trying to reload my grid periodically. I came across the solution:

```
var grid = $("#list"),
    intervalId = setInterval(
    function() {
        grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{current:true}]);
    },
    300000); // 300 sec === 5 min
```

but i'm not sure where to put this piece of code. does it go inside `loadComplete` ? I am already using

```
jQuery("#list").trigger("reloadGrid", [{current:true}]);
```

like this

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({...

    jQuery("#list").trigger("reloadGrid", [{current:true}]);

...});
```

i dont understand where to access the

```
intervalId
```

please help,.
thanks

Oleg, this is what i tried as per your answer:

```
    // above this line is the grid code including nav grid

    jQuery("#refresh_list").click(function(){
        jQuery("#list").setGridParam({datatype: 'json'});
      //  jQuery("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");
      setInterval(function() {
            $('#list').trigger("reloadGrid", [{current:true}]);
        alert("hello");}, 2000);
            });
    });   //This is the end of the document.ready function
```

am I placing the setinterval function correctly ? is it supposed to be inside the grid or outside ? is it supposed to be inside the document.ready or outside ?
**surprisingly, the alert pops up as you would expect !** but the grid does not reload. i know because i am making changes to the database and they are not reflected in the grid. when i click the refresh button then it displays current data as expected. I want it to reload periodically and always have the most recent data from the database.

by the way these are the gridoptions i am using

```
    pager: "#pager",        //Identifying the navigation bar
  rowNum: 500,          // how many rows to display on page 1
  rowList: [500,1000, 2000, 3000,4000], //values for the dropdown which specifies how many rows to show 
  sortorder: "desc", //the order of sorting by default
  viewrecords: true, // displays total number of rows
  gridview: true,   // the full grid body will be placed on the page as one operation
  autoencode: true,
  height:400, //height of the grid
  ignoreCase:true,// case insensitive search
  multiselect:true, // checkboxes before each row
  multiboxonly: true,
  loadonce:true, //for client side sorting, searching and pagination
  caption:"This is me", // caption for the grid header
```

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out this way :

```
  window.setTimeout( refreshGrid, 8000);
 function refreshGrid()
 {
    jQuery("#refresh_list").click();
    window.setTimeout(refreshGrid, 8000);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just small misunderstanding. If you want reload the grid every 5 min you should execute the code

```
grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{current:true}]);
```

every 5 min. The standard JavaScipt function [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) help to do this. If you execute

```
setInterval(function() {
    grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{current:true}]);
}, 300000); // 300 sec === 5 min
```

then the callback function with `grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{current:true}]);` will be already executed every 5 min. So the grid will be reloaded like you want.

Saving the result of `setInterval` in a variable like in your original code

```
var grid = $("#list"),
    intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{current:true}]);
    }, 300000); // 300 sec === 5 min
```

is helpful if you need **to stop automatic reloading** of the grid. For example if the user start editing of one row you can stop reloading by

```
clearInterval(intervalId);
```

after the user submit the changes of discard it you can execute the same `setInterval` one more time to start automatic reloading. So the variable `intervalId` is required only if you want to stop the periodical execution of the callback function used in `setInterval`.

Comment: thanks oleg ! but i am still not getting the desired result. i placed the code as you said. kindly look at the edit

Comment: @user2334092: I see in your code that you call `setInterval` inside of `jQuery("#refresh_list")`. What if the user clicks **more as once** on the button? You should call `setInterval` either outside of `jQuery("#refresh_list").click` then refreshing will be permanently every 2 sec or you have to save the value returned by `setInterval` in variable and cancel previous set permanent reloading by calling `clearInterval`.

Comment: thanks. i tried calling it outside the refresh list but still the grid does not reload. i still get the alerts popping up. one strange thing i noticed is that when i include the setInterval function, my VERTICAL SCROLLBAR does not hold still ! I was trying to look at some data by scrolling down but as soon as i scrolled down, the scrollbar would shoot right back to the top ! I guess in some way the grid is being reloaded. that would explain why the scrollbar keeps going to the top. but the data is not being updated

Comment: do you think there is something wrong with my grid parameters ? i am using JSON data. I have to use refresh list as I want to implement client side sorting, searching and pagination. thats why I have to convert it to local when the data comes in but to query the URL's i have to convert them to JSON so that i can pass the proper parameters. do you think this might have something to do with the reload ? the refresh button works perfectly fine by the way.

Comment: @user2334092: Sorry, but I have to do some things before I fly in the vocation with my family. I'm afraid that I will be not accessible till the middle of august. Best wishes!

Comment: no problem Oleg ! thanks for all your help all this time. Have a great time ! where are you going by the way ?

Comment: hi @Oleg, I still haven't been able to resolve this issue. as before, my grid keeps reloading data from the local cache instead of going to the url. if possible, could you please try to implement a small test grid which keeps reloading its data from the url at specific intervals ? thanks